# Is there a way to handle nested collection without ORM framework in DDD?

Tags: c#, ado.net, repository, entity, domain-driven-design

I am puzzled on handle nested collection in business object via pure ADO.NET solution without 3rd-party ORM frameworks, such as AutoMapper/NHibernate/EF.

Please considering the following scenario:

```
//SalesOrder
public class SalesOrder
{
    ICollection<IOrderItem> OrderLines { get; set; }
}
```

If we retrieve a SalesOrder entity from database by its repository object like this,

```
//Retrieve entity via repository object
ISalesOrderRepository repo = new SalesOrderRepository(DbContext);
ISalesOrder order1 = repo.GetOrderByCustomerPo("TN-2202-01");
```

We can use SQL statement to query data from database and fill data into the corresponding properties of SalesOrder entity.

But how to initialize the nested collection object of order1.OrderLines?

I think there is a way to build up order1.OrderLines by Proxy Pattern like this:

```
public ICollection<IOrderItem> OrderItems
{
    get 
    {
        if(_orderItems == null)
        {
            IOrderItemLazyLoadingProxy lzProxy = new OrderItemLazyLoadingProxy(this);
            _orderItems = lzProxy.Load();
            return _orderItems;
        }
    }
}
```

I am confused about the above implementation that the domain object is directly coupled with or depend on a proxy object.

So I want to know whether there is a way can handle nested collection transpaerncy in an aggregate root object?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want them lazy loaded?

Comment: Well, lazy loaded is not necessary, I would like to discuss it as non-lazy-loading.

Comment: What is DbContext in the above code if you are not using an ORM?

Comment: Please consider DbContext as pseudo code or placeholder for a database connection or transaction object wrapper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your domain objects should have *Persistence Ignorance*.  They should not be concerned with persistence concerns directly but you should still be pragmatic.

A repository is responsible for loading an aggregate in its entirety so your `SalesOrderRepository` should load the items also.  You could go with something along these lines:

```
public class SalesOrder
{
    private readonly List<SalesOrderItem> _items = new List<SalesOrderItem>();

    public IEnumerable<SalesOrderItem> Items
    {
        get { return new ReadOnlyCollection<SalesOrderItem>(_items); }
    }

    public void AddItem(string product, decimal price)
    {
        OnAddItem(new SalesOrderItem(product, price));
    }

    public void OnAddItem(SalesOrderItem item)
    {
        _items.Add(item);
    }
}
```

Your repository would fetch the item date and instantiate them.  The `OnAddItem` is used for historical data and only to populate the internal list whereas the `AddItem` is an actual domain command indicating that something new has happened.

Just some ideas :)

Comment: Yes, but how about nested collection within nested collection, for example, a IList<IEmployee> ManagedStaffs of an Employee entity in an orgnization? is lazy loading the only way for this case?

Comment: Try to avoid lazy-loading like the plague.  It really has no place in DDD.  When you are faced with such a situation you need to look at your design.  You aggregates may not be well-defined.  Find a way to break those dependencies.  You may be missing some domain concept.

Comment: Another point to remember is that you shouldn't use your object model for querying as that tends to lead one down the navigation path where one object needs the next needs the next...

Comment: Thanks for your help, that's really usefully and fixing my DDD idears, and one more question, do you know any public real-world app/project that implemented with DDD model?

Comment: A have a *very* basic, i.t.o. DDD, process management sample here: https://github.com/Shuttle/Shuttle.Esb.Samples/tree/master/Shuttle.ProcessManagement.  I'll also be applying DDD and Event Sourcing to my Sentinel project: https://github.com/Shuttle/Shuttle.Sentinel.  Perhaps they'll give you some ideas.  Most real-world stuff would usually be something done at a client so not public :(